# Which Json library to use if I am doing manual memory management

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, sbjson

I have code that has to be comptaible with 10.5 till 10.8 mac os x. I am doing manual memory management because of lack of ARC on 10.5.

I need to incorporate some third party json library in the project to be able to handle json. I am pretty new to Objective-c and cocoa. I am concerned whether I should be worried about what memory managment that library is doing ?

In my opinion I should not use a lib that does ARC , am I correct ? if that's the case I would need your recommendation as to which json lib should I use which does manual memory management.

There seems to be SBJson which however does ARC I am guessing it won't suit my needs.

Any advice for this new comer please ?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how ARC works. ARC is a compile-time technology; as long as your compiler supports it, you can deploy on older OS versions. (With some exceptions, in particular regarding weak pointers.)

Comment: Can you use GC on the older platforms and ARC on newer ones? Or do you have to use a single binary that caters to all platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit 
Very high performance (usually by an order of magnitude compared to other JSON libs), easy to use. Doesn't require ARC. 
To be more precise, JSONKit doesn't support and probably will not support ARC, so if you are planning to switch to ARC in the future, keep that in mind.

Answer (score -1):

ARC inserts retain/release calls at compile time, so as long as you use a compiler that supports ARC (you compile on 10.8, say) you should be OK. (There might be some features, like weak pointers, that are not supported.)

Comment: ARC is not compatible with Leopard, even without weak references. The minimum deployment target for which ARC is supported is 10.6. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/